# Webview doesn´t display correctly in android

Tags: javascript, android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I´m using appcelerator studio %.2.0 GA webView with chartjs plugin line update.

With this code below, I have a perfect view in web browser like Chrome (without webview), but on android smartphone or emulator it not runs correctly. Appears a red line on the bottom and double line on the strokeGrid.

Does anybody help ?

This is the code:

Javascript-

```
var count = 0;

//
// create base UI tab and root window
//
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
title:'BtTest',
backgroundColor:'#eff2d8',
    layout: 'vertical'
});

var mainView = Ti.UI.createView({
    top: 0,
    width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    backgroundColor: '#7cd0F7',
});

var webView = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    backgroundColor: '#F0F8FF',
    top:100, 
    left: 0,
    height: Ti.UI.FILL, 
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    cacheMode: Ti.UI.Android.WEBVIEW_LOAD_NO_CACHE,
    borderColor: 'black',
    url: 'html/lineChart.html'
}); 
mainView.add(webView);

function send(value)
{   
    Ti.App.fireEvent("app:fromChart", {message: value});
    Ti.API.info('Sent: ', value);
    count ++;
    Ti.API.info("Count: " + count);
}

function interval()
{
    setInterval(function()
    {   
        send(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
}, 500);
}   

interval();
win.add(mainView);
win.open();
```

HTML-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script src="../js/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="updating-chart" width="320" height="220"> </canvas>
<script>
    var N = 20;
    var zero_array = [];

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    zero_array.push("");

    var canvas = document.getElementById('updating-chart'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    startingData = {
    labels: zero_array,
    datasets: [
    {
        strokeColor: "rgba(255,0,0,1)",
        data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    }]
    },
    latestLabel = startingData.labels[0];  
    var lineOptions = {
    bezierCurve: false,  
    scaleOverlay : false,
    scaleOverride : false,
    scaleSteps : null,
    scaleStepWidth : null,
    scaleStartValue : null, 
    scaleLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,1)", 
    scaleLineWidth : 1, 
    scaleShowLabels : true,
    scaleLabel : "<%=value%>",
    scaleFontFamily : "'Arial'", 
    scaleFontSize : 12, 
    scaleFontStyle : "normal", 
    scaleFontColor : "#666", 
    scaleShowGridLines : true,
    scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
    scaleGridLineWidth : 1, 
    pointDot : true,
    pointDotRadius : 0,
    pointDotStrokeWidth : 1,
    datasetStroke : true,
    datasetStrokeWidth : 2,
    datasetFill : false,
    animation : false,
    responsive: false,
    maintainAspectRatio: true
    };

// We wait for everything to be loaded
window.onload = function main() 
{
    // Get the context of the canvas
    var ctx = document.getElementById("line_example").getContext("2d");
    // Create the Chart object
    var line_example_chart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data,lineOptions);
    // Used for the labels on the X axis
    var label_idx = 1;
    Ti.App.addEventListener("app:fromChart", function(e)
    {
        var msg = e.message;     
        if(msg == 0) msg = 1;           
        line_example_chart.removeData();
        line_example_chart.addData([msg], label_idx++);                
    });
    window();
};
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug. Thanks for that! Could you check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, please create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building for an older version of android, the webview for appcelerator was not Chromium based which might cause things to look a bit different. You can read more about it [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView).

A quote from the WebView documentation for appcelerator:

> Starting with Android 4.4 (API Level 19), the WebView component is based off of Chromium, introducing a number of changes to its rendering engine. Web content may look or behave differently depending on the Android version. The WebView does not have full feature parity with Chrome for Android.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. I´m using android version 6.0 api 23. Tried to change browse internal to external but the result was the same.